# WSO2 AuthenticationAdmin service access - connect timed out

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

While trying to publish public API via WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 and I get the following error:

```
{org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} - Unable to sendViaPost to url https://mydomain:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

It's strange since the error occurs on TEST and PROD only. (DEV environment is doing fine.)

My assumption is that AuthenticationAdmin is a service of WSO2 Identity server which is somehow configured for my DEV and not for TEST nor PROD.

Is that right? If so - where could I look for the configuration of authentication services within API Manager?

BR

Comment: Is the address reachable? Try a curl request from your server to https://mydomain:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin to find out

Comment: Invoking curl to DEV endpoint gives <faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/AuthenticationAdmin and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring> while invoking curl to appropriate QA endpoint ends up with "Connection timed out"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the service can not send the message in TEST and PROD environments. As it is perfectly working in DEV environment, may be the Service takes much time to response back in TEST and PROD environments . Could you please increase the time out and retry this ?

Comment: I do not have any option in increase this time in API Manager. However I am convinced that this is not the issue as the curl request timeouts after a couple of minutes which should be enough for service to respond